# empty column: object is 'float' and has no len()

Tags: python, maxlength

Bu running this code I'm trying to filter the files that it reads, one of those filters is:

> if the file has 'SOURCE' column then: if the lambda len().max() of
> 'SOURCE' column is > 0, we can conclude is not empty, then follow the
> code...

BUT!! if column 'SOURCE' it's empty, it's telling me that **is a 'float' and therefore it's got no length in form of an error**. I'm just trying to filter: **if the column ' SOURCE' is empty, not row by row but the entire column, then do this else do that**...

```
for f in files_xlsx:
wb = load_workbook(input_path + "\\" + f, read_only=True)
if 'New Leads' in wb.sheetnames:
    df = pd.read_excel(input_path + "\\" + f, sheet_name="New Leads")
    colre = [col for col in df.columns]
    for eo in colre:
        df.rename(columns={eo: eo.replace('*','').replace('**','') for eo in colre})
    dtcol = [col for col in df.columns if "Date" in col]
    for ex in dtcol:
        df.rename(columns={ex: "Activity Date"}, inplace=True)
    cols = df.columns
    if "SOURCE" in cols:
```

> ```
>         if df.dtypes['SOURCE'] != 'float':
>             if df.SOURCE.map(lambda x: len(x)).max() > 0:
> ```

```
                df.dropna(how = 'all')
                df['File'] = f
                df_xlsx = pd.concat([df, df_xlsx], ignore_index=True)
                df_xlsx = df_xlsx[["Email","SOURCE","File","Activity Date"]]
            else:
                df_ns = df_ns.append([f], ignore_index=True)
        else:
            df_ns = df_ns.append([f], ignore_index=True)
    else:
        df_ns = df_ns.append([f], ignore_index=True)
else:
    df_ns = df_ns.append([f], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what your question is.  The code you provide seems to test for the 'float' case.  Is this code working, or not?  If it is not, what is the problem?

Comment: A _collection of `float`s_ has a length; an _individual float_ doesn't. You can't meaningfully call `len()` on an individual float, just on a collection of them.

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
This is the error that it shows, its column coming from an excel file that it should contain a large code but it the column is empty it should take a different path.